# Python turtle: Print input text at a specific coordinate in the window

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

For my first ever assignment, my instructor has requested that we receive string input from the user, output to a variable, and display that user input at a certain coordinate on the turtle window before actually drawing a five point start at another set of X,Y coordinates.

Not entirely sure how I get the turtle package to output my string input from the user at a certain point in  the window. I have googled everywhere and I see how to get the user input and assign that to a variable, just not the actual coordinate in the turtle window.

Comment: Move the turtle to where the text should be and call [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.write)

Comment: More generally, checking your course material and reading the documentation should always be among your first reflexes. SO should come almost last... ;)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I did refer to my course material and there is a good deal of ambiguity in the materials.

Comment: Trust the documentation, it is usually very well written and complete.

Comment: I suggest breaking the assignment down into small steps then google: "python turtle get input from user site:stackoverflow.com", then "python turtle write text on screen" etc. There is an existing solution to each sub-step and I agree that the turtle docs are fantastic. There is some underspecification here--is the user supposed to input on the terminal or in a pop-up window? What does "output to a variable" mean?

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your response. I will also try what you have suggested here. 

As far as the user input goes, I am running my .py file and within a dialogue box, I need to ask the user for their name and then that is to be output to a variable that I can call somehow and show in the turtle graphics window at a certain coordinate. 

This goes well above my head and isn't really discussed at length anywhere on the internet that I have been able to find.